# Do any records of the building of the First Parish Church of Norwell exist?

Tags: united-states, parish-register, massachusetts, church-records, property-records

The First Parish Church of Norwell has records back to 1642 and has
scanned all of the church records to facilitate historical and genealogical research.
See http://www.firstparishnorwell.org/archive.htm

My understanding is [James Sparrell](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Person%3aJames_Sparrell_%282%29) was involved in the building of the church.
Werelatelink cites a reference showing he was a member of the church in 1820.

Do any records exist of the building of the church?

Answer (score 5):

Here are photos of a family heirloom given to my grandfather as recognition for many years of service with the Scituate Historical Society. It is a framed picture of the church with what we believe is the proposal for building it. It is addressed "To the Gentlemen Committee for Building a Meeting House in the South Parish". It is from -or what we think appears to read- James N Sparrell, George A Robbins, Elnathan Cushing Jr.

It's header states "Scituate Feb 22 1830" (or 1820)?

The proposal gives two options based on the spire on the cupola- $2,650 or $2,750.

[image: Photo of church and proposal in its entirety]
[image: Cover of proposal]
[image: Photo3]
[image: Photo4]
[image: Signatures]